# How to fix NextJS webpack error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, storybook

I generated `NextJS` project using `TypeScript` template and I want to add my `Storybook` to the project. `Storybook` is written in `TypeScript`. When I'm adding Storybook to my NextJS project I'm getting such webpack error: `"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file "`. Both NextJS and Storybook are using webpack 5.  How is possible to fix this error?

Here is full error which I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Does this file come from a file outside the project root directory?

Comment: It's file inside node_modules folder, node_modules is in the root of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is not transpiled. You can try using `next-transpile-modules`.